# How to add values on excel according to their types?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I'm currently tallying data using Excel here is the format of my data

The hierarchy of the Test area is test1, test2 then final test. Ideally the total units should comprise only of the data from their highest test_area level. For example Mat1 the data should only come from the Final Test because this is its highest test_area level. While the Mat2 and Mat3, the data should only come from the test_area Test2.

***sample data***

[image]

Comment: You sure the output for Mat2 is correct currently?

Comment: Mat2 should be 1006     55. I made a mistake on the output. Thanks for noticing.